# Formatting string( where string represents a session) into date format using moment js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, momentjs

i have a variable **value** that is giving me the data as "*Session between Jan 15 2022 4:00Am And Jan 15 2022 4:30Am*", i want to format this date string into "*Session between 15-01-2022 4:00Am And 15-01-2022 4:30Am*".

Things i have tried:

```
//function to remove "session between and" so that the date can be parsed.
public removeUnwantedText(words : any){
        var cleanUpWords = ["Session","between","And"];
        var expStr = cleanUpWords.join("\\b|\\b");
        return words.replace(new RegExp(expStr, 'gi'), '').trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ');
    }
//calling the function and trying to format date string,where value="Session between Jan 15 2022 4:00Am And Jan 15 2022 4:30Am"

 console.log(moment( this.removeUnwantedText(value),"MMM DD YYYY h:mmA").format('[Session between] DD-MM-YYYY  h:mmA [And] DD-MM-YYYY  h:mmA'));
```

the console ouptut is : *Session between 01/15/2022 4:00Am And 01/15/2022 4:00Am*

but the required output is  *Session between 01/15/2022 4:00Am And 01/15/2022 4:30Am*

Any kind of help and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The console output is correct because you're outputting the same date to both places. Maybe you need to split the string on `'And'` and then replace the dates separately?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will try out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Iaxmy!

You don't actually need moment for this. The `Date` object will accept `Jan 15 2022` in the constructor. You can use a regex to extract and replace the old strings with the new ones.

```js
  reformatString(string: string) {
    //Find the dates
    const matches = string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+/g);
    if (!matches) throw new Error('Failed to parse string');

    //Convert to new format
    const newStrings = matches.map((s) => {
      const date = new Date(s);
      const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const year = date.getFullYear();
      return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    });

    //Replace with new strings
    matches.forEach(
      (match, index) => (string = string.replace(match, newStrings[index]))
    );

    return string;
  }
```

The regex searches for: word, number, number, all separated by a space.

You can also change this line if you wanted the DD-MM-YYYY format.

```js
return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by RobG, `new Date(string)` is implementation dependent. So I suppose you should avoid and use an external library like moment instead. It actually condenses this answer quite a bit.

```js
  reformatString(string: string) {
    //Find the dates
    const matches = string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+/g);
    if (!matches) throw new Error('Failed to parse string');

    //Convert to new format
    const newStrings = matches.map((s) => {
      return moment(s, 'MMM DD YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    });

    //Replace with new strings
    matches.forEach(
      (match, index) => (string = string.replace(match, newStrings[index]))
    );

    return string;
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mk8ifz?file=src/app/test/test.component.ts

Comment: The format of "Jan 15 2022" is not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris Hamilton for providing a better solution. I learned something new.

Comment: Hey no problem, although RobG made a good point above. I updated my answer to avoid using the Date constructor.

Comment: thanks again @Chris Hamilton, that was the reason why I was using "moment()", but my code wasn't up to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @evolutionxbox, I tried it out and it works like that.
below is the final code I wrote :

```
//function to remove gibberish words so that the value in the description column can parse the date.
    public removeUnwantedText(words : any){
    let cleanUpWords = ["Session","between","And"];
    let expStr = cleanUpWords.join("\\b|\\b");
    return words.replace(new RegExp(expStr, 'gi'), '').trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ');
   }
 //splitting the description data with And as breakpoint and storing them separately
     let sessionDate = value.split('And');
     let sessionStart = sessionDate[0];
     let sessionEnd = sessionDate[1];

  //formatting the date string into DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A format.
   let sStart = moment(this.removeUnwantedText(sessionStart),["MMM DD YYYY h:mmA"]).format('[Session between] DD-MM-YYYY  h:mmA');
   let sEnd = moment(this.removeUnwantedText(sessionEnd),["MMM DD YYYY h:mmA"]).format('[And] DD-MM-YYYY  h:mmA');
           
//concatenating both the results into one and returning the output.
       let res = sStart +' '+ sEnd; 
       console.log(res);
```

The console gives me the expected output.

Thanks to everyone who helped me.